# Is it possible to fit in a ternary operator as the termination in a for loop?

Tags: java, operator-keyword, ternary, termination

So, I just want to know if its possible to slip in any code or a ternary operator inside the termination bit of a for loop. If it is possible, could you provide an example of a ternary operator in a for loop? Thanks!

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
   statement(s)
}
```

Comment: As always, the easiest thing is to try it.

Answer (score 6):

The `termination` clause in the `for` statement (if supplied - it's actually optional) can be any expression you want so long as it evaluates to a `boolean`.

It must be an *expression*, not an arbitrary code block.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can since only thing here is `termination` should be a `boolean`

```
for (int i=0; i==10?i<5:i<6; i++) {


}
```

But what is the point of this?

Things to remember. Termination condition of a `for` loop should be a `boolean`

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, it is possible:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < someCondition ? first : second ; i++) {
    ...
}
```

you can use ternary operators or any expressions in all three parts of the loop header:

```
for (int i = flag ? a : -a ; i != (flag ? 2*b : -2*b) ; i += flag ? 1 : -1 ) {
    ...
}
```

If you need to insert more complex logic into the termination condition, a good approach would be to define a method: it usually improves readability of your loop:

```
boolean checkCondition(int i) {
    ...
}

...

for (int i = 0 ; checkCondition(i) ; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `termination` part of the `for` loop requires a `boolean` condition. You can pass anything that gives a boolean value for the `termination` part.

For ex:

```
for (int i = 0; i<5?true:false; i++) 
{

}
```

Comment: `i < 5 ? true : false` is of cause just equal to `i < 5`, so perhaps not a great example...

Comment: @Alnitak: I know. I follow the KISS principle.