# Is it possible to make the variable increases or decreases in a for-loop based on a boolean in Java?

Tags: java

I know it is easily achievable through an if/else-statement with two different for-loops, but what I'm asking about is if it's possible to do something like:

```
for(int a = 0; a < value ; boolean ? a++ : a--){
}
```

But that only leaves the error "not a statement" in my compiler.

**EDIT:** The `a<value` isn't a big issue. I'm okay with this being an infinite loop in both directions with a break-condition inside the for-loop.

Comment: did you try it?? let us know..

Comment: `boolean` is a type. Not a variable.

Comment: @LoganKulinski I know. But I want the int a to increase or decrease based on the boolean.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpa Yes. I tried it. The compile gave me an error.

Comment: @AndreasEvjenth Why not try it with a variable?

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a for loop at all. What exactly are you trying to do? (See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/26158610/1743880)

Comment: @Tunaki in short, I'm copying an sub-array from an array of about 400 elements. It starts at a specific point and copies 4 elements, but if it starts at   398 it will copy number 398, 399, 400 and then throw an outOfBoundException, so instead I want to copy 398, 397, 396 and 395. I know this is easy with an  if/else statement with two different for-loops, but I was wondering if it was possible with 1 for-loop with an boolean condition.

Comment: Even if it would work, if bool == false, depending on value your loop would either be run forever (if value if greater than 0) or not at all (if value is <= 0).

Comment: @Ridcully that is correct, yes. But I'm not really interested in that. In fact, I'm okay with it being an infinite loop in both directions. It's just that the for-loop had some much inside it, that the whole method would be far more readable if it was just one of them. But most of all, I was just curious if it was possible at all, but struggled to find any good answers (perhaps I searched with the wrong keywords).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can technically use a ternary operator in the [`[ForUpdate]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-ForUpdate) part of a `for` loop. The syntax for it would be:

```
for (int a = 0; a < value; a += bool ? 1 : -1){
    // ...
}
```

where `bool` is of type `boolean`. It will either increment or decrement `a` depending on whether `bool` is `true` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it.

The third statement in a for-loop it's just an expression that evaluates once per iteration. You're getting a compilation error because the ternary operator needs an assignment in order to be valid.

```
boolean ? a++ : a--
```

Instead here's another way of doing the same

```
boolean b = true;
int a = 0;
for (; a < value; a = b ? a + 1 : a - 1) {
    //Your code
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: a = b will not work as one is an int and one is a boolean